# Setting up vncserver on OpenSolaris zone

Tags: solaris, vnc, opensolaris, zones

I am running OpenSolaris 5.10 and set up a sparse zone(inherits most of bin directories from global zone). I ended up copying many etc and var files from global zone, eventually most of the stuff(firefox,gvim, etc.) working through ssh via X11. However, I am having problems setting up vncserver on the zone. This is what I get if I tried to start the vncserver.

```
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5911
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
_X11TransNAMEDOpenClient: Cannot open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X11 for NAMED connection
_X11TransOpen: transport open failed for local/%zone%:11
xsetroot:  unable to open display '%zone%:11'
_X11TransNAMEDOpenClient: Cannot open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X11 for NAMED connection
_X11TransOpen: transport open failed for local/%zone%:11
_X11TransNAMEDOpenClient: Cannot open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X11 for NAMED connection
_X11TransOpen: transport open failed for local/%zone%:11
_X11TransNAMEDOpenClient: Cannot open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X11 for NAMED connection
_X11TransOpen: transport open failed for local/%zone%:11
vncconfig: unable to open display "%zone%:11"
twm:  unable to open display "%zone%:11"
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %zone%:11
```

I already chmoded /tmp/.X11-pipe with 777, and there is no pipe in /tmp/.X11-pipe or /tmp/.X11-unix directory.

Here is my cat /etc/release:

```
                 OpenSolaris 2009.06 snv_111b X86
   Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                Use is subject to license terms.
                      Assembled 07 May 2009
```

BRAND: ipkg

Comment: That's the output to stderr.  What if you truss it?

`truss -f -o /var/tmp/vncserver.truss vncserver (...)`

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what OS you are running as there is no such thing as OpenSolaris 5.10. Moreover, copying /etc and /var files from the global to a non global zone is usually a wrong approach.
Please clarify the OS version used (cat /etc/release) and the kind of zone used (sparse, whole root, branded, ipkg, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, although it appears that you can create a sparse zone in Opensolaris, they are not supported, and will probably be eliminated. The preferred root is a whole root zone (Big Zone). You will then have to download the packages required into the new zone, using the pkg command. I am currently trying to do this, but you must have the network configured correctly (interface, resolv.comf, nsswitch.dns etc ), and this must be done manually (no dhcp support in a zone) Hope this helps